# Rewrite rational function as the sum of a polynomial and partial fraction?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I know how to approach this with a higher degree in the numerator with division but not the other way around.

Can someone give me a hint?

$$f(x) = \frac{(x^2 + x - 2)}{(x^4 + 2x^3 - 3x^2)}$$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition
First step: factorize the denominator,

Comment: Did you complete this problem @sabrinapat?

Answer (score 0):

Note that factoring numerator and denominator gives
$$
f(x)=\frac{(x+2)(x-1)}{(x+3)(x-1)x^2}
$$